# loop through list box in vb and get a total amount

Tags: vb.net, loops, listbox

I’m trying to loop through a list of prices on a list box and print the total in a textbox on the form. The loop I have works, but the figures it produces are all wrong!. can any one help me??

the figures look ok but then when i add more items to the list box the total amount goes all wrong.

```
Public Class f

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'LoftDataSet.Services' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.ServicesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LoftDataSet.Services)

    'Loop through all the rows that are in the dataset
    For Each dr As DataRow In LoftDataSet.Services.Rows

        Dim btn As New Button 'Instantiate a button
        btn.Text = dr("service_name").ToString 'UserName is a field in my Users Table
        btn.Size = New Size(140, 80)
        btn.Tag = dr("ID") 'Here we set the tag to the primary key (ID)

        'Since we're using a flowlayoutpanel, we don't need to worry about setting the location property
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn) 'Add the button to the flow layout panel
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf UserClick  'Here we give the button a handler for the click event

    Next
End Sub

Public Class Product
    Public Property ProductName As String
    Public Property ProductCost As Decimal

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return ProductCost & "      " & ProductName
        'Here you could build a formatted string to the user to include cost
    End Function
End Class

'Here we write our method for the click event of the button(s) we created
Dim SelectedProduct As New Product
Private Sub UserClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    'We set a filter to the binding source passing it ID=<and whatever is stored in the tag property>

    ServicesBindingSource.Filter = "ID = " & DirectCast(sender, Button).Tag.ToString

    SelectedProduct.ProductName = DirectCast(sender, Button).Text
    SelectedProduct.ProductCost = DirectCast(ServicesBindingSource(0), DataRowView).DataView(0)(2)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(SelectedProduct)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For i As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndices(i))
    Next
End Sub




Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim aValue As Decimal
    For Each item As Product In ListBox1.Items
        aValue += CDec(item.ProductCost)
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = aValue



End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I see you are adding "Product" to the listbox, i.e. ProductCost and Product Name. In this case i guess just  " sum += Val(CStr(Listbox1.Items(i)))" , should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cycle through each item using an integer as your count.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        MsgBox(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString)    
Next
```

Or you can add it to an integer/double value

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        MyInteger += Double.Parse.ListBox1.Items(i).ToString) 
Next
MsgBox(MyInteger)
'Now the messagebox will show your total
```

EDIT:
Do not use ListBo1.Items.Item(i). Access directly through Listbox1.Items(i)

Comment: ok I made new changes to code above. it works but the addition of numbers in list box are incorrect. am I missing something??

Comment: what would cause the addition of numbers in listbox to go wrong. works with 2 items then goes wrong if you put 5 or 6 items in

Comment: Take out your step -1. For i As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1 To 0  will automatically step -1, adding in the step -1 might just stuff it up. Also just add a msgbox(i.tostring) inside the for loop to see what results you are getting, might assist in finding the loop problem as well